# Eclipselink: Clear Cache when using ReadAllQuery

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm having trouble clearing my cache.

I have a simple ReadAllQuery.

```
    Session session = ((EntityManagerImpl) em).getActiveSession();

    ReadAllQuery query = new ReadAllQuery(Customer.class);
    query.setFetchSize(100);

    query.useScrollableCursor();

    ScrollableCursor cursor = (ScrollableCursor) session.executeQuery(query);


    int count = 0;
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Customer customer = (Customer) cursor.next();
        if (++count > 0 && count % 100 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Fetched " + count + " entities");
            em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
        }
    }
```

I also tried using `em.clear()` and

```
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
```

in the persistence.xml but the Heap Space keeps growing.
How do I clear the entities?

Thank you

Comment: First you need to determine what is holding onto the memory, which can be done with a memory profiling tool.  It could be the driver itself, in which case using pagination might be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
em.createNamedQuery("findAll").setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_RETRIEVE_MODE, CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS).getResultList();
```

As you can see in javadoc of the `BYPASS` enum:

> Bypass the cache: get data directly from the database.